# monthly job in sql server agent not running

Tags: server, scheduled-tasks, jobs, agent

[image]we have a planed job which should run yearly on Jan, 1st.
It does not start, so for testing we schedueld the job to start on Feb, 1st (today) - but it did not start again without any messages. Our daily / weekly jobs are running well, so the agent itself seems to work. Any hints ?

Job should run. We can't see any false options